# Обмен данными между приложениями

Tags: android

Есть 2 приложения A и В. Приложение В должно выполнять свои функции, только при условии, что пользователь авторизован в приложении А.

Можно было бы при авторизации в приложении А сохранять в БД информацию, что пользователь авторизован в приложении А, а в приложении В просить пользователя ввести идентификатор и проверять информацию в БД.

Минусы: Нарушение конфиденциальности. Пользователь может ввести идентификатор другого пользователя.

Вопрос: Как это проверить (локально) на устройстве пользователя?

Answer (score 3):

Для этого необходимо реализовать связку [ContentProvider](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers?hl=ru) и [AccountManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager). Про эту связку есть отличное видео от Яндекса [Account Manager: аккаунты, токены и все-все-все](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=he1bIvgSqvQ&t=1090s).